# The probability of raining (is my solution correct?)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> A three day festival is being planned to be held in a location with the following weather characteristics:
>
> 1. The probability of rain on any given day is 0.06.
> 2. If it rains on a particular day then the probability that it also rains on the next day is 0.37.
> 3. If it rains for two days in a row then the probability that it will rain on the following day is 0.21.
>
> What is the probability that it will rain on any day during the festival?

Here is my solution:

Let $i$ denote the event it rains on the $i$th day.

$P(i)$ is the probability that it rains on the $i$th day.

$P(i^c)$ is the probability that it does not rain on the $i$th day

\begin{align*}
P(1 \cup 2 \cup 3) &= P(1)+P(2)+P(3)-P(1 \cap2)-P(2 \cap 3)-P(1 \cap 3)+P(1 \cap 2 \cap 3) \\ &= 0.06+0.06+0.06-P(2|1)P(1)-P(3|2)P(2)-P(1 \cap 3)+P(3|1,2)P(2|1)P(1) \\ &= 0.18-0.37 \cdot 0.06-0.37 \cdot 0.06 - P(1 \cap 3) + 0.21 \cdot 0.37 \cdot 0.06 \\ &= 0.18-0.0222-0.0222-P(1 \cap 3)+0.004662 \\ &= 0.140262-P(1 \cap 3)
\end{align*}

We couldn’t get $P(1 \cap 3)$ directly, but we could calculate $P(1 \cap 3)$ in terms of $P(3|1,2^c)$:

[Venn diagram intuition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRe36.png)

\begin{align*}
P(1 \cap 3)&=P(1\cap2\cap3)+P(1\cap2^c \cap 3)
\\&=
P(3|1,2)P(2|1)P(1)+P(3|1,2^c)P(2^c|1)P(1)
\\&=0.21\cdot 0.37\cdot0.06+P(3|1,2^c)\cdot(1-0.37)\cdot0.06
\\&=0.004662+0.0378\cdot P(3|1,2^c)
\end{align*}

Since the lower bound (if the first day rains, the second day no rain, the third day always no rain) of $P(3|1,2^c)$ is $0$, and the upper bound (if first day rains, second day no rain, the third day always rain) is:

\begin{align*}
max(P(3|1,2^c))&=P(3|2^c)
\\&=
P(3)-P(2 \cap 3)\\
&=P(3)-P(3|2)P(2)\\
&=0.06-0.37\cdot 0.06\\
&=0.0378
\end{align*}

so the upper bound of $P(1 \cap 3)$ is:

\begin{align*}
max(P(1 \cap 3))
&=0.004662+0.0378\cdot P(3|1,2^c)\\
&=0.004662+0.0378\cdot0.0378\\
&=0.00609084
\end{align*}

Thus $P(1 \cap 3)$ is between $[0, 0.006]$, and the probability that it will rain on any day during the festival is between $[0.134,0.14]$

Comment: It seems correct. And the explanation is quite clear.

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems that P(any day) = 1 - P(no day) = 1-0.94^3=0.17.

Comment: @infinitezero I think P(no day) is not 0.94^3, because each day stay dry is not independent events. 

e.g. if the 1st day is dry, the probability of the second day still stay dry is not 0.94 anymore